# How do you know when to cast an item in swift?

Tags: swift

I see it done all the time but don't know how other coders know when to cast an item. Here is an example that recently had me wondering how the coder knew to cast the item:

```
let item = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Item", inManagedObjectContext: ad.managedObjectContext) as! Item
```

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_casting

Comment: Thanks Matt - will be reading that

Answer (score 1):

The [`insertNewObject(forEntityName:into:)` API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEntityDescription/insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:) that you're describing returns a NSManagedObject, which is the way new managed objects are created, configured and returned to you to make use of.

In CoreData, all NSManagedObjects saved are actually subclasses of the NSManagedObject base class, so if you want to `let item =` from that call, you'll need to cast it to the actual subclass type it's supposed to be.

Makes sense?

Comment: Hi Michael, are you saying that NSManagedObjects are subclasses of NSManagedObjectContext?

Comment: And yes, the first part makes clear sense; still working on understanding the second part ---- but how would one know that something is being returned? ----- did we know that something is being returned before we are assigning the results of the function into a variable?; in this case the variable being 'item'

Comment: No, in your example above, the class Item (with a upper case I -- this is a bad name for an example, b.t.w.) is a subclass of NSManagedObject.  NSManagedObject is the type of object returned by `insertNewObjectForEntityForName`.  So to use item (lower case i) after it's been created, you need to cast it to be the correct type.

Comment: A managed object context, on the other hand, is a [`represents a single “object space” or scratch pad in an application. Its primary responsibility is to manage a collection of managed objects.`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/) (as seen in the introductory paragraph to this Apple documentation).

Comment: ok got you on the subclass part; but suppose we were looking for a rule to create that can be applied to all classes and not just NSManagedObject; how could we know when we an item being returned is not the item we need and that we need to cast it?

Comment: That is what my book tries to explain to you in the section I pointed you to. It's because you need to send a message to this object that the subclass can receive that the superclass cannot.

Comment: sorry michael, here is what my comment was supposed to say: "ok got you on the subclass part; ----------- How about a rule we can create that's appliable to all classes and not just NSManagedObject?

Comment: @michael:  How can we know when an item being returned is not the item we need, essentially meaning we will need to cast it...  ?

Comment: Hi, @matt, I really appreciate the patience. And thanks for the help! I came up with a few additional questions. If you would have a moment to follow up on them that would be great and really appreciated! ----  Here are the questions I created:  -------- 1) What exactly was it your book is explaining? There is A LOT to read and I'm kinda strapped on time. I'd like to put in a good hour into reading it. 2) Which message are we sending to which object? 3) Which class here is the super class? --- I'm sure there are many others who'll come across this that will also greatly appreciate so thank you

Comment: The link points you to the section on casting. It explains casting. Your question is about casting.